# Do pushouts exist in a cartesian closed category?

Tags: category-theory

If $C$ is a cartesian closed category, then is it necessary that all pushouts exist?

Comment: Don't believe so...  It simply requires products and for the product functor $(A\times-)$ to be left adjoint. Don't think it even entails completeness, though I'm failing to think of counterexamples to either at the moment.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Of course completeness is not automatic. Look at $\mathbf{FinSet}$.

Comment: I should have said "*finite* completeness", not just "completeness". I'm sure there's a counterexample to that as well, I just can't name one at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Take the full subcategory $\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathbf{Set}$ generated by $2$ and closed under finite products and exponential objects. It is clear that $\mathcal{C}$ is precisely the full subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$ consisting of the finite sets whose cardinality is some power of $2$, and by construction $\mathcal{C}$ is cartesian closed. $\mathcal{C}$ is clearly not closed under pushouts: if it were, then we would be able to find a three-element set in $\mathcal{C}$ as the pushout of $2 \leftarrow 1 \rightarrow 2$. Moreover, because $2$ is a coseparator in $\mathbf{Set}$, we see that any colimits in $\mathcal{C}$, if they exist, *must* be constructed the same way as in $\mathbf{Set}$. So the pushout simply does not exist in $\mathcal{C}$. Incidentally, $\mathcal{C}$ does not have pullbacks either.